# Compare rows in two sheets

Tags: excel, vba

I have 6 sheets in an Excel document.
[image]

I would like to compare two sheets.

Sheet 1 (Artikelstammdaten) has 8555 Lines
[image]

Sheet 2 (Warengruppen) has 232 Lines
[image]

My Code:

```
 Sub WorksheetLoop()

 Dim Current As Range
 Dim Element As Range
 Dim wgRow As Integer
 Dim wbRow As Integer
 Dim Warengruppe As String
 Dim Warengruppebezeichnung As String

 Dim Stamm1 As String
 Dim Stamm2 As String
 Dim Stamm3 As String
 Dim Summe As String

 wgRow = 2
 wbRow = 2

 For Each Element In Sheets("Artikelstammdaten").Range("R:R")

    Warengruppebezeichnung = Sheets("Warengruppen").Cells(wbRow, 1).Value
    Warengruppe = Sheets("Artikelstammdaten").Cells(wgRow, 18).Value

    If Warengruppe = Warengruppebezeichnung Then
        Stamm1 = Sheets("Warengruppen").Cells(wbRow, 2).Value
        Stamm2 = Sheets("Warengruppen").Cells(wbRow, 3).Value
        Stamm3 = Sheets("Warengruppen").Cells(wbRow, 4).Value
        Summe = Stamm1 + ">" + Stamm2 + ">" + Stamm3

       Sheets("Artikelstammdaten").Cells(wgRow, 18).Value = Summe

       wbRow = 2
       wgRow = wgRow + 1
    Else
        wbRow = wbRow + 1

    End If
    Next

 End Sub
```

It works but breaks off at line 1755.

Comment: Do you realize that you are likely processing several million blank cells?

Comment: What do you mean by **Breaks off**? Does it give you any error codes? Or is it no response?

Comment: When it "breaks off", do you get any error?

Comment: You are iterating through every cell in column "R", and assigning that cell to the variable `Element`. You never ever ever use that though... your iterations are 100% pointless. You might as well just do `For i = 1 to 1000000` and loop in that. I think you need to take a step back from this code and rethink it.

Comment: I disagree with _100% pointless_, OP uses `wgRow` for scanning through `Column R`. And I'm sure that this is the reason OP got only 1755 iterations. When `wbRow` is not matched, it cost 1 loop for searching next `wbRow`.

Comment: So I would say it is 80% pointless. :)

Comment: There is no error message - he just stops at line 1755. Everything is right up to the line what he does.

Comment: The reason it stops is because it gets to a point where there is no match found `Artikelstammdaten` for whatever `wbrow` it's on. It can never increment to the next `wgrow` since the incrementing of that row in `Artikelstammdaten` is held in the `IF` condition that there must be a match, and so it just iterated nearly a million times and then stops. Again... I really think you need to take a step back from this, explain what you are trying to accomplish here (share some sample data and desired results if you want us to help further) and rewrite. There is a lot of things not making sense here

Comment: Also that For loop is 100% pointless in that it could be replaced with `For 1 = 1 to 1000000` and the exact same logic would take place. At least writing it that way acknowledges that there is no good reason we are iterating through column R as part of this loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you got only 1755 iterations is that you waste many loops to find the matching value in `Sheets("Warengruppen")`. Use a wiser way, `Range.Find(What:=key)` method returns a range object with the same key. Note it will return `Nothing` if nothing is matched, so we need to check if it is found or not for preventing an error.

```
Sub WorksheetLoop()
    'current is crying because you never call her :/
    Dim Current As Range
    Dim Element As Range
    Dim wbFound As Range

    Dim Stamm1 As String
    Dim Stamm2 As String
    Dim Stamm3 As String
    Dim Summe As String

    For Each Element In Sheets("Artikelstammdaten").Range("R:R")

        Set wbFound = Sheets("Warengruppen").Range("A:A").Find(What:=Element.Value)

        If wbFound Is Nothing Then
            Debug.Print "Not Found with Row# " & Element.Row
        Else
            Stamm1 = wbFound.Offset(0, 1)
            Stamm2 = wbFound.Offset(0, 2)
            Stamm3 = wbFound.Offset(0, 3)
            Summe = Stamm1 + ">" + Stamm2 + ">" + Stamm3

            Element.Value = Summe
        End If
    Next Element
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works now for the whole lines.
However, he now also makes up to line 65535 always a ">>>" although in the lines nothing is in it.

Comment: You can set the range such as `Range("R2:R9000")` in stead of `Range("R:R")`. Further more, a `Range("R1:R" & UsedRagne.Rows`) or `Range("R1", Range("R" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))` or anything can determine the last cell of column R will help.